# Constructing a set of time series using R

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to find an optimal way to deal with a set of time series data. In my dataset there are several objects (thousands, one in a row), each one having a set of attributes (with median and variance) for a couple of irregularly spaced dates (tens). The first rows of the table look like this:

```
"2012-08-14_ari-1_median" "2012-08-14_ari-1_variance" "2012-08-14_bai_median" "2012-08-14_bai_variance" "2012-08-14_blue_median" "2012-08-14_blue_variance" ... 
"1" 20.388762 3.1271796 0.2533784 0.0374 0.89685684 0.054375805 ...
"2" 25.483303 5.3743725 0.37641725 0.0323 0.89529204 0.05524634 ...
"3" 10.6717825 5.784709 0.52881724 0.0724 0.5804015 0.3661
...
```

My goal is to perform temporal analysis of the attributes of data. Therefore I would like to create the most effective way to store the data. It is easy to create the data frame with all the data. My problem is how to include time. Current thoughts would be creating something like this:

```
    ari-1                                  bai
    2012-08-14 2012-08-21 2012-09-01 ...   2012-08-14 2012-08-21 2012-09-01 ...
"1" 
"2" 
"3" 
...
```

Another option would be:

```
    2012-08-14         2012-08-21         2012-09-01
    ari-1 bai blue ... ari-1 bai blue ... ari-1 bai blue ...
"1" 
"2" 
"3" 
...
```

Is this possible to achive? Is this even a good method? What are other better options?

I tried this with the xts and created an object from part of the data frame (transponded the df first):

```
           "1"       "2"       "3" ...
2012-08-14 0.9804026 0.8968568 0.8952920 0.5804015 0.3915596
2012-08-21 0.8128355 0.8878272 0.8045192 0.8428068 0.8696688
2012-09-01 0.6153219 0.4710921 0.4936159 0.5018827 0.7701396
```

This means that my xts is only a couple of rows (tens of dates), but many (thousands) of columns. And this is only for one attribute.

Any help to a R newbie would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might suspect, there are a bunch of ways to do this and all have benefits and drawbacks.

#### Three dimensional data structure

The simplest approach when it comes to creating the data object might be to leave your data frame structured as is, and add a temporal component by making a list of data frames, with each item of the list being a snapshot in time.

```
frame_time <- function(t) {
    a = rnorm(5, t, 1)
    b = rnorm(5, t, 2)
    c = rnorm(5, t, 3)
    data.frame(a, b, c)
}
d <- lapply(1:10, frame_time)
```

If you're new to R, it may look like it's going to be a pain to extract time-series data from this object. But you can use the fact that indexing with `[` is actually a function (running `` `[`(x, y, z) `` is the same as `x[y,z]`), and pass it to one of the `apply` functions, like so:

```
sapply(d, "[", 1, 1)
```

(Where `"["` is because `sapply` can look up functions by name as well as by passing the actual function - useful in cases like this.) This gets the element in the 1, 1 position at each item stored in your list of data frames.

There are a couple of other ways to do essentially the same thing, that is, put your data in a three-dimensional structure. Which margins you choose for what is a matter of trade-off between convenience of creating the data set and convenience with accessing it later on, so you should choose the one that works best for you.

#### Long format data

An entirely different approach would be to use a long format data set. This type of data structure relies on ID variables for each data point; in your case, these might be time, object number, and measurement (`ari-1_median`, for example). A simplified version of your data set might look like this:

```
  time variable object         value
1    1        a      1  0.0003081319
2    2        a      1 -1.3294403879
3    1        b      1 -0.1419320288
4    2        b      1 -0.9520839796
5    1        a      2 -0.8922036126
6    2        a      2 -1.8102263590
7    1        b      2 -1.1126900256
8    2        b      2 -0.2621680731
```

Getting your time-series in long format data is a simple matter of using the ID variables (here I've put the long-format data above into a data frame `e`):

```
 e$value[e$variable == "a" & e$object == 1]
```

The `reshape2` package provides many tools for working with long format data and transitioning between long format and wide format, which is a little more human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do analysis of data, you should try to follow standards of data formatting that are best described in the reshape library. Basically, try to use same style that Oracle or any other SQL table would give you.

In your case, I believe data frame would look like that:

```
variable   measurment      measurment_number       date          value
 ari         median               1              2012-08-14    20.388762
 ari        variance              1                 ...           ....
 ari         median               2              2012-08-14     20.111
```

etc.
This way you will be able to easily use libraries like dplyr and others to summarize and analyze your data.
To organize your data in such manner I highly recommend looking into [reshape library](http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html) and particularly into function **melt**.

Answer (score 0):

Both @user164385 and @Zakkery suggested to use a long format data set. After subseting the main data frame, a simple `melt` from the `reshape2` and some column reformatting has provided the dataset in a form suitable for the analysis.

```
  REGION_ID       date   var   stat      value
1         1 2012-08-14 ari-1 median         NA
2         2 2012-08-14 ari-1 median         NA
3         3 2012-08-14 ari-1 median 108.190330
4         4 2012-08-14 ari-1 median  20.388762
5         5 2012-08-14 ari-1 median  25.483303
6         6 2012-08-14 ari-1 median   8.646864
```